# Python: merging json change "÷" to "\u00c3\u00b7"

Tags: python, json

I tired encoding utf-8 and cp1252  but have similar output

For illustration purpose, file1.json = file2.json

```
[{"subject":"Math","operation":[{"sign":"÷"},{"sign":"+"}]}]
```

Python code

```
json_files = ["file1.json", "file2.json"]    
def merge_JsonFiles(json_files):
  merge_jsonFile = 'merged.json'
  result = list()
  for f1 in json_files:
    # with open(f1, 'r', encoding='cp1252') as infile:
    # with open(f1, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    with open(f1, 'r') as infile:
      result.extend(json.load(infile))

  with open(merge_jsonFile, 'w') as output_file:
    json.dump(result, output_file)
    
merge_JsonFiles(json_files)
```

Comment: Try setting `ensure_ascii` to `False`. *If `ensure_ascii` is `True` (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped*

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
import json

json_files = ["file1.json", "file2.json"]    
def merge_JsonFiles(json_files):
    merge_jsonFile = 'merged.json'
    result = list()
    for f1 in json_files:
        with open(f1, 'r') as infile:
            result.extend(json.load(infile))

    with open(merge_jsonFile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
        json.dump(result, output_file, ensure_ascii=False)

merge_JsonFiles(json_files)
```